# How to handle JSON format inconsistencies with Swift 4 Codable?

Tags: ios, json, swift4, codable, jsondecoder

I need to parse JSON of which one of the field value is either an array:

```
"list" :
[
    {
        "value" : 1
    }
]
```

or an empty string, in case there's no data:

```
"list" : ""
```

Not nice, but I can't change the format.

I'm looking at converting my manual parsing, for which this was easy, to `JSONDecoder` and `Codable` `struct`'s.

How can I handle this nasty inconsistency?

Comment: I agree, you should give a dope slap to whomever created that web service. They should, at the very least, return `"list": null` if there's no list, rather than changing the type of the results! But, in answer to your question, you will have to write an `init(from:) throws` method that manually tries decoding `list`, gracefully handling when it is a string. See `init(from:)` example [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

Comment: If your *manual parsing* works, don't change it. The magic of `Codable` (adopt the protocol and you are done) happens only if the JSON is consistent.

Comment: @Rob It's only the New York Times API.

Comment: Lol. It's still wrong. It deserves a bug report. Out of curiosity, which endpoint are you using?

Comment: @Rob Endpoint: https://api.nytimes.com/svc/mostpopular/v2/mostviewed/all-sections/7.json?apikey= that's without my personal apikey, which can easily obtained from https://developer.nytimes.com/signup  It's `"{ results" [ { "media" : <array or empty-string>,  ... }, ...] }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to try decoding it one way, and if that fails, decode it the other way. This means you can't use the compiler-generated decoding support. You have to do it by hand. If you want full error checking, do it like this:

```
import Foundation

struct ListItem: Decodable {
    var value: Int
}

struct MyResponse: Decodable {

    var list: [ListItem] = []

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        do {
            list = try container.decode([ListItem].self, forKey: .list)
        } catch {
            switch error {
            // In Swift 4, the expected type is [Any].self, but I think it will be [ListItem].self in a newer Swift with conditional conformance support.
            case DecodingError.typeMismatch(let expectedType, _) where expectedType == [Any].self || expectedType == [ListItem].self:
                let dummyString = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .list)
                if dummyString != "" {
                    throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .list, in: container, debugDescription: "Expected empty string but got \"\(dummyString)\"")
                }
                list = []
            default: throw error
            }
        }
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case list
    }

}
```

If you want no error checking, you can shorten `init(from:)` to this:

```
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        list = (try? container.decode([ListItem].self, forKey: .list)) ?? []
    }
```

Test 1:

```
let jsonString1 = """
{
    "list" : [ { "value" : 1 } ]
}
"""
print(try! JSONDecoder().decode(MyResponse.self, from: jsonString1.data(using: .utf8)!))
```

Output 1:

```
MyResponse(list: [__lldb_expr_82.ListItem(value: 1)])
```

Test 2:

```
let jsonString2 = """
{
    "list" : ""
}
"""
print(try! JSONDecoder().decode(MyResponse.self, from: jsonString2.data(using: .utf8)!))
```

Output 2:

```
MyResponse(list: [])
```

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer! But I'll stick with my manual traversing the object tree as it's fairly simple and easy to follow.

Comment: Further thoughts: Because this is an ugly/stupid format mistake, I'm leaning towards fixing the JSON input string (little code replacing `"list":""` with `"list":[]`). I'm aware it's less generic and assumes `"list":""` does not occur elsewhere. This enables the use `Decodable`. A small pragmatic fix for an ugly problem; I like that.